Is it possible to use the results from Abaqus Standard as a predefined field in Explicit analysis? If so, how is the time mapped between the analysis?
I have nodal results from an Abaqus UEL subroutine, where I am solving coupled heat and moisture transport. I have three degrees of freedom in this analysis and several more state variables. I want to utilize their time-varying values in my subsequent mechanical analysis, which is a dynamic explicit step. The time step for my Standard analysis is 2000 seconds, while the time step for my Explicit analysis is 1 second. Do you have any idea how the time will be mapped between the analysis??
